# A (bi)alternant formula for Wronskian

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, determinants

We know that there exists similarities between power functions and derivative of a function (in particular, Newton binomial formula and Leibniz rule for derivation of a product can be deduced from each other). Thanks to the alternant formula, we can express the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix with a missing power (e.g. see [Computing an almost Vandermonde matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3024496/computing-an-almost-vandermonde-matrix)) via a power function of its coefficients.

**Question**: Does there exist a similar formula for the Wronskian of arbitrary functions :

$$
W_k(f_1,\dotsc, f_{n}) = 
\begin{vmatrix}
f_1&\cdots&f_1^{(k-1)}&f_1^{(k+1)}&\cdots &f_1^{(n)}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
f_n&\cdots&f_n^{(k-1)}&f_n^{(k+1)}&\cdots &f_n^{(n)}
\end{vmatrix}?
$$

Comment: One case is easy: $W_{n-1}(f_1,\ldots, f_{n})$ is the derivative of the Wronskian $W(f_1,\ldots, f_{n})$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an instance where the two formulas are very close: if $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ are fundamental solutions of a linear ODE with indeterminate (constant) coefficients. This is explained in the elegant paper

[L. Gatto, I. Shcherbak: "On one Property of one Solution of one Equation" or Linear ODEs, Wronskians and Schubert Calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.3345)

Moscow Mathematical Journal, 2012, Volume 12, Number 2, Pages 275–291

(the link is to the freely available arXiv version)

I doubt that much further can be done. Already the first nontrivial case of $$W_1(f,g,h)=\det\begin{pmatrix}f&f''&f'''\\ g&g''&g'''\\ h&h''&h'''\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
looks somewhat mysterious: the second derivative of the Wronskian is
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}f&f''&f'''\\ g&g''&g'''\\ h&h''&h'''\\ \end{pmatrix}
+
\det\begin{pmatrix}f&f'&f''''\\ g&g'&g''''\\ h&h'&h''''\\ \end{pmatrix},
$$
and I do not see any way to use other formulas to split out one of these summands!